# iOS 14 App Development: How to avoid empty string on app delete alert (alert for delete/move to App Library)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios14

It appears that iOS 14 has a new alert that appears when a user tries to delete an app. For the app I'm developing, it's showing an empty string (`""`) instead of the app name (see screenshot).

Why is my app's name missing, and how can I specify this string (in Xcode, in a .plist file, etc.)?

[image: Screenshot of alert to prompt delete/move to App Library]

Comment: It's the bundle display name (`CFBundleDisplayName`). I have no idea why it's missing for your app.

Comment: @matt Is `CFBundleDisplayName` the same string that defines the name of the app (right below the app icon on the iOS home screen)? That string is definitely showing up, so yeah it's weird that it's fine on the home screen but missing in this alert.

Comment: @sunw Can you post your Info.plist code??

Comment: @sunw Did you end up solving this? I am dynamically setting the `CFBundleDisplayName` and I'm also having this issue (strangely enough only on one of the apps where I'm doing this).

Comment: @Thijs This issue resolved itself after updating to this year's Xcode (13+). My plist is as follows:
`
 <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
 <string>$(APP_DISPLAY_NAME)</string>`
I don't have a dynamically-changing CFBundleDisplayName.

Comment: @sunw Thanks for replying. I'm actually using the same entries in my plist, that's what I meant by dynamically setting it. Guess it's time for me to update my Xcode. Still weird that I'm only encountering this issue with one of my apps...